# I want to get the field data from FireStore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get ['startTime] in this method.

But I can't get it.

I get the following error

> The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting
> the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
> 'data'.

```
  Future<String> getStudyTime()async {
    final getStartTime =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(uid()).get().data()['startTime'];
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final formatTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(now);
    var hh = now.hour;
    var mm = now.minute;
    var hhmm = "$hh:$mm";
    studyTime = int.parse(hhmm);

    return studyTime;
  }
```

[FireStore Image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calling `get()` returns a `Future`, so you need to use `await` **on `get`** to get its value:

```
final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(uid()).get();

final getStartTime = doc.data()['startTime'];
```

If you want to do this in a single line, use parenthesis to ensure the `await` works on `get()`:

```
final getStartTime =
  await (FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(uid()).get()).data()['startTime'];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hey @damnexpress. Any update here?

Comment: I was able to clear it.thanks